# Show that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v=n!$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to know how to prove that
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v=n!
$$
I wanted to use that
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{n}e^{-t}\text{d}t=n!
$$
and use $v=t^n$ but it didn't work because I obtained that it is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}v^{1/n}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v
$$

Comment: the sub that you suggest should work if you leave things in terms of $t$.

Comment: Your substitution is correct. Check your calculation again.

Comment: Okay i will check that again thanks

Comment: Apply $t^n=v$ on $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v$$ with $$\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}v^{1/n}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v$$ you need integrating by parts!

Comment: Thanks @MyGlasses but that's what i've done ^^. That's it, integrating by parts ! thanks !

Comment: @Atmos You could take instead the substitution $t^{n+1} = v$ in your second equation.

Answer (score 4):

It works well

$v=t^n$ then $ dv=nt^{n-1}dt$

And $ e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}=e^{-t}$

$$I=n\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{n-1}dt=n\Gamma(n)=n!$$

Comment: But what about the $n$ with $\text{d}v$ ?

Comment: Horrible notation.

Comment: atmos $\gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ you need n to get n!

Comment: I guessed now integrating by parts will solve the thing up !

Comment: you could or use the definition of gamma function @Atmos

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed substitution is $t=\sqrt[n]{v}=v^{\frac1n}$.
Then $v=t^n$, $t=0$ when $v=0$, $t=+\infty$ when $v=+\infty$ and

$$dt=\frac1n v^{1-\frac1n}\,dv=\frac1n\,\frac1{\sqrt[n]v}v\,dv,$$

that is, $dt=\frac1n\,\frac1t\,t^n\,dv\implies dv=nt^{n-1}\,dt$.
So, after the substitution, you get

$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt[n]{v}}\text{d}v=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t}\,nt^{n-1}\,dt
$$

Can you take it from here?